# Connecting to TCP Server using GPRS Connection

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have *Motorola MC75* and I can connect to my Office TCP Server from home using Wi-Fi connection without any problem and send/receive files. But when I use GPRS connection I can not connect to my Office TCP Server.

I have made sure that GPRS is connected to internet(i.e. I can go to explorer and surf the web using GPRS connection(I have turned off wireless at this point)). Can any one help me on this issue. Your help will be appreciated.

Interesting thing is that I have PC at my home and I have static address at home. I can run my TCP Server on my one of the PC at home and I can connect to my home PC from outside using GPRS connection and send and receive data files. But If I try to connect to my Office PC it does not work(My office has static IP address as well). But when I use wireless connection it works fine at my office PC.

I have tried *Optus* and *Vodafone SIM* Cards and it did not work.

Comment: What port does your office machine listen to? Perhaps your providers block that port for some reason.

Comment: I have written TCP Server and both places I use Port Number 1127. Interestingly when I am at home and instead of using GPRS I connect to my office using my home wireless network it works fine. But when I try to connect using GPRS it does not connect.

Comment: Does your home wireless connection have a VPN connection to your workplace?

Comment: No I do not have VPN to my office. There is a static address in the office and I connect using static address.

Comment: So port 1127 on your office IP is properly forwarded to your office PC, your device has a working internet connection, your provider doesn't block port 1127 and still the device can't connect? Then there must be a firewall or routing issue. What kind of firewalls and devices are between your office PC and the internet? Anyway this looks like it's not a programming issue but a configuration one, try at http://superuser.com/. What does actually happen when you try to connect?

Comment: It gives me connect error. Instead of GPRS if I use wireless connection to my router at home to internet to my office pc it works fine. I do not have much idea about my office firewall but technical at office says every thing is fine at our side. They connected android device to server and showed me.

Comment: My MC70 handheld computer has Windows Mobile 6.5 classic OS.

Comment: _"They connected android device to server and showed me"_ - did that Android device use GPRS and connect to your PC on port 1127? And _what_ error do you get when connecting?

Comment: Just because you have GPRS "internet access" on your phone doesn't mean it's full and open internet access.  Many mobile providers only allow certain traffic (e.g. www, email etc.) from mobiles and block other traffic.

Comment: If I connect to my home PC GPRS works fine. Only when I connect to Office it does not work. They are saying they are forwarding TCP Port 1127 and disable firewall on this port.